# Printing DYMO barcode on 64Bit Office fails using VBA. But works on 32Bit Office

Tags: vba, ms-access, dymo

I have a Windows 10 PC running Office 64Bit. When I try to print a DYMO Barcode label, it fails. But works fine on 32Bit Office. I'm programming in MSAccess using VBA.

I reach out to DYMO and they said:
"We have different version of SDK, DLS SDK is out dated and DYMO is not supporting DLS SDK anymore."

I am only a VBA level programmer and not sure what steps to take next.
Maybe someone has run into this before?

The code fails on line 10 below. "429 ActiveX component can't create object"

```
Dim DymoAddIn As Object
Din DymoLabels As object

10 Set DymoAddIn = CreateObject("Dymo.DymoAddIn")
20 Set DymoLabels = CreateObject("Dymo.DymoLabels")
```

Comment: Looks to me like you need to install a 64 bit version of their software?

Comment: Likely the version of the SDK you have installed is 32-bit: you can't automate that from 64-bit VBA.

Comment: Tim and braX, I kind of thought the same thing, but the people at DYMO didn't mention that. They sent me to a web page with regard to the SDK, but as a VBA level programmer, it didn't help me.

Comment: Well, at this point, I'm kind of stuck. If anyone out there thinks they could help maybe with some programming, let me know. Dymo did send me to an SDK page with Framework info, but I'm just not familiar enough with that level of coding.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out(with no help from DYMO). There is a newer version of the COM object which gets installed using this link.

http://labelwriter.com/software/dls/win/DLS8Setup.8.6.1.648.exe

BUT WARNING! The file is not on a secure server (HTTPS:\). I am not sure why and have asked DMO for a explanation. So, if anyone comes across this situation, just be aware of this.